# How to access data in multidimensional array using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, multidimensional-array

I am using ajax to make a call to the server and get back some user data. The server returns back an array formatted like below:

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => array:17 [▼
    "id" => 334
    "provider" => "some_provider"
    "option_id" => "x124223"
    "option_title" => "title"
    "api_parameter" => "parameter"
    "chart_title" => "title"
    "chart_color" => "#6a76fc"
    "chart_target" => "2220"
    "chart_type" => "line"
    "chart_size" => "4"
    "chart_data" => array:7 [▼
      239 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 2114
        "created_at" => "14/August"
      ]
      240 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 2114
        "created_at" => "15/August"
      ]
      241 => array:2 [▶]
      242 => array:2 [▶]
      243 => array:2 [▶]
      244 => array:2 [▶]
      245 => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    "average" => 2122.0
    "current" => array:2 [▶]
    "last" => array:2 [▶]
    "current_status_icon" => "md-trending-neutral"
    "current_status_color" => "#3DDCF7"
    "status_message" => "hmm... The needle didnt move."
  ]
  1 => array:17 [▼
    "id" => 345
    "provider" => "some_other_provider"
    "option_id" => "x124"
    "option_title" => "Title"
    "api_parameter" => "parameter"
    "chart_title" => "title"
    "chart_color" => "#6A76FC"
    "chart_target" => "Set a target"
    "chart_type" => "line"
    "chart_size" => "4"
    "chart_data" => array:7 [▼
      202 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 5
        "created_at" => "13/August"
      ]
      203 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 5
        "created_at" => "14/August"
      ]
      204 => array:2 [▶]
      205 => array:2 [▶]
      206 => array:2 [▶]
      207 => array:2 [▶]
      208 => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    "average" => 5.0
    "current" => array:2 [▼
      "data" => 5
      "created_at" => "16/August"
    ]
    "last" => array:2 [▼
      "data" => 5
      "created_at" => "16/August"
    ]
    "current_status_icon" => "md-trending-neutral"
    "current_status_color" => "#3DDCF7"
    "status_message" => "hmm... The needle didnt move."
  ]
```

I then try to access the data within the array using a foreach loop

```
$.ajax({url: "/url/to/server", success: function(result){
    result.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log(item['chart_data']['data']);
    });
  }, complete: function() {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
      setTimeout(checkForUpdates, 3000);
    }
  });
});
```

But this just logs `undefined`. How do I access the chart_data nested within each of the top level arrays?

Comment: You need to access the nested array: `chart_data` is an array, which has elements that have the `data` property. So you'll need another nested loop

Comment: @trincot Thanks I tried this. I got an error that reads `Uncaught TypeError: item.chart_data.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Where is that JSON output coming from? PHP? The syntax is not correct. It would be useful if you would include in your question the output you get when doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))`. That way we will see the correct JSON.

Comment: @trincot Yes the json output is from php. Console.log shows something similar but just set as array objects.

Comment: All I can say is that it is not JSON (arrays with length 17 should have 17 indices, not 17 properties). Please provide the console.log output I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure is not clear, as the structure you have shared is output in PHP notation, and does not represent the JSON you receive in JavaScript.

But my guess is that this will work:

```
result.forEach(function(item) {
    Object.keys(item.chart_data).forEach(function (key) {
        console.log(item.chart_data[key].data);
    });
});
```